# Looking to return data from a table using option buttons, search box and button control

Tags: excel, vba, filter, search-box, radio-button

Hell all,   I'm looking to be able to have text entered into a box commanded by a search button.  So, if looking at the imgur link, I want to be able to enter the text "Corporate" in the search box (TextBox21) while having the "Site" option button ticked (OptionButton21) I want to them click the CommandButton21 and have all items with "Corporate" for the site showing in the table.  I've read a lot of things online but really having difficulty tying all the elements and events together.   Any help would be much appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3o78.jpg  (snip of my spreadsheet)  and my code is below, however it's admittedly pretty blank.  I just have the elements there with no coded actions because I haven't had any success with what I've tried.

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton21_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton22_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton23_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox21_Change()

End Sub
```

Comment: You only need `Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()` for your function. You need to access the text of by using something like `TextBox21.text` --- similarly optionbuttons probably have something like `OptionButton22.value`

Comment: Oh yuck, after looking into it the only way I could find to get the value of option button 1 was `Sheet1.Shapes("Option Button 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value`, which is 1 if selected, -4146 if not.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue? If not, let me know, I might be able to help